# PiVPN Routing Problem

Tags: raspbian, networking, vpn

I've recently installed PiVPN on a newly created Pi system and I am able to connect to it ok from a remote client that I created. The problem is that although I'm able to access the node where my VPN server is installed (using SSH and ping) from my client, I'm unable to access any of the other nodes on my network (even by using IP addresses) or the internet. It looks like a routing problem but I don't know how to fix it.

Technical info:

- Home network subnet: 192.168.100.0/24
- Broadband router: 192.168.100.79
- RPI system: 192.168.100.7
- VPN subnet: 10.8.0.0/24

Please can someone advise how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

[This excellent post](https://www.stavros.io/posts/how-to-configure-wireguard/) by Stavros Korokithakis should help, specifically:

> #### Accessing your home LAN
>
> To actually access the server’s LAN, you’ll need to make a slight modification to the configuration. On the
> server’s config file [`/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf`], at the end of the
> the `[Interface]` section, add these two lines:
>
> ```
> PostUp   = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
> PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
> ```
>
> This assumes that your LAN interface is called `eth0`. If it isn’t, change the lines above to the actual name.
>
> On the client, add your LAN’s subnet under AllowedIPs. For example, if
> your subnet is 192.168.1.x, change AllowedIPs to look like this:
>
> `AllowedIPs = 192.168.2.0/24, 192.168.1.0/24`

Therefore for your configuration, the client's `AllowedIPs` would be:

- `AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.0/24, 192.168.100.0/24`

or you could forward all traffic from your client over the Wireguard tunnel with:

- `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::0/0`

And you'll also need to [enable IP Forwarding](https://www.ducea.com/2006/08/01/how-to-enable-ip-forwarding-in-linux/) if you haven't already

Answer (score 0):

You need a static route added to your router. When you establish a  vpn connection you will have a different ip network from your home network. All the devices on your home network look to your home router (gateway) for the path to other IPs. If the gateway does not know how to get to the VPN network then the devices will not be accessible.

Add static route with destination of the vpn network and next hop of the ipaddress on your home network for the pi.

Destination 10.8.0.0/24
Next hop 192.168.100.7

The solution the other poster (Andrew) mentioned would also work. Just a different approach. Static route vs NAT